# Computing row counter variable in python

Tags: python, pandas

How to compute a variable (through an easy function) which is a row_counter of sorts.

For instance, suppose i have a data which is at Customer_ID level and has all transactions for each customer_id. I want a field created, which sorts transactions from earliest to latest data and assigns a counter variable

I am doing it slightly convoluted manner like below

```
 cust_df['row_count'] = 1
    cust_df = cust_df.sort_values(['cust_id', 'transaction_date'])
    cust_trans_num = cust_df .groupby(['cust_id', 'transaction_number'])['row_count'].count().reset_index()
    cust_trans_num = cust_trans_num .groupby(by=['cust_id', 'transaction_number']).sum().groupby(
        level=[0]).cumsum().reset_index().rename(columns={'row_count': 'cust_trans_number'})
    cust_df = pd.merge(cust_df , cust_trans_num , how='left', on=['cust_id', 'transaction_number'])
```

Input data is like below:

```
cust_id  transaction_number  transaction_date
1           ABC1             1/1/2018
1           DEF3             12/31/2017
1           XYZ2             4/1/2017
```

Output data should be like below:

```
cust_id  transaction_number  transaction_date   cust_trans_number
1           XYZ2             4/1/2017            1 
1           DEF3             12/31/2017          2
1           ABC1             1/1/2018            3
```

Let me know if there is a one-line solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

1. `pd.to_datetime` to convert your column to datettime type
2. sort your dataframe by `cust_id` & `transaction_date`
3. finally `GroupBy.cumcount`

```
df['transaction_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['transaction_date'])

df = df.sort_values(['cust_id', 'transaction_date'])

df['cust_trans_number'] = df.groupby('cust_id').cumcount().add(1)
```

**Output**

```
   cust_id transaction_number transaction_date  cust_trans_number
2        1               XYZ2       2017-04-01                  1
1        1               DEF3       2017-12-31                  2
0        1               ABC1       2018-01-01                  3
```